# An error occurred (ClientException) when calling the DescribeTaskDefinition operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am facing issue while describing ecs task definition via running thorugh bitbucket pipeline.

Issue i face is like below,

An error occurred (ClientException) when calling the DescribeTaskDefinition operation

command i use to execute via shell script in bitbucket pipeline as below,

```
LATEST_TASK_DEFINITION=$(aws ecs describe-task-definition  --task-definition ${TASK_FAMILY})

echo $LATEST_TASK_DEFINITION \
                 | jq '{containerDefinitions: .taskDefinition.containerDefinitions, volumes: .taskDefinition.volumes}' \
                                          | jq '.containerDefinitions[0].image='\"${DOCKER_IMAGE}\" \
                                                           > /tmp/tmp.json
```

```
aws ecs register-task-definition --family ${TASK_FAMILY} --cpu 256 --memory 512 --network-mode awsvpc --requires-compatibilities "FARGATE" --task-role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/ECSTaskExecutionRole --execution-role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/ECSTaskExecutionRole --cli-input-json file:///tmp/tmp.json
```

[issue in bitbucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3EPb.png)

But when i am running same commands from linux terminal its running.

Anyone face such kind of issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with `jq -r`.

Comment: @Marcin let me use this option. Thx

Comment: this issue is closed now. Thanks @Marcin

Comment: Did it work? I can provide a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue when I was setting up an ECS cluster, task definition file, and service using Terraform.

It also happened at the point of deployment to an already set-up ECS cluster using Circle CI.

I get the error below when I run `terraform apply` or when I try to deploy using Circle CI:

> An error occurred (ClientException) when calling the DescribeTaskDefinition operation: Unable to describe task definition.

**Here's how I resolved it**:

**For Terraform**:

The issue had to do with a typo in the **cluster name** that was not correct with how the **service** was referencing it. All I had to was to delete the name for the **cluster name** and had to retype it. This time the service was able to reference it correctly.

**For Circle CI**:

The issue had to do with a typo in the **cluster name** environment variable for the Circle CI project that was not correct with how the **service** was referencing it. All I had to was to delete the **cluster name** environment variable and I had to set the correct **cluster name** environment variable. This time the service was able to reference it correctly.

**Reference**: [Unable to describe task definition](https://github.com/silinternational/ecs-deploy/issues/145#issuecomment-407415560)

Comment: > I've only seen this error when I have a typo in either the cluster name or service name. 

This excerpt from the reference link is the shortest answer. I have resolved my issue by fixing the service name.